# Mount a WebDav drive to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, webdav

How do I mount a WebDav drive to Google Colab? Any incites would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following workaround to download a WebDav file to mounted Google Drive.

```html
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive")
!wget -c --http-user=user-id --http-password=password "https://webdav.site.com/folder/filename.ext" --no-check-certificate
```